# "DEBUG" Error when installing any new packages in python via Anaconda Powershell Prompt

Tags: installation, powershell, python, debug, runtime-error

When I attempt to install packages via the conda install command (e.g. `conda install rasterio`) I receive a ridiculous looking debugging error in the powershell prompt.

It ultimately tells me that the issue is resolved and the packages are installed, but when I attempt to run my code within jupyter notebook, I receive multiple errors for simple things such as syntax errors within the scripts of the downloaded packages, whcih I didn't even write myself.

These are widely used packages, so I don't think the problem lies within them. I have attached an image of the debugging screen.

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First Uninstall `rasterio` Then Try to this package with conda run one of the following:

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken rasterio`

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 rasterio`

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/dev rasterio`

And then Check it.